# Where does $p^t$ come from in $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\not\mid b, \text{ for some prime-}p \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

*Background:*

**Exercise 14:**

Let $p$ be a fixed prime integer and let $R$ be the set of all rational numbers that can be written in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ with $b$ not divisible by $p. Prove that

*(a)* $R$ is an integral domain caontaining $\mathbb{Z}$.  [Note $n=\frac{n}{1}$].

*(b)*  If $\frac{a}{b}\in R$ and $p\nmid a$, then $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit in $R.$

*(c)* If $I$ is a nonzero ideal in $R$ and $I\neq R$, then $I$ contains $p^t$ for some $t>0.$.

*Questions:*

I have a question about part (c) above.   Specifically, If $R$ is defined as $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\not\mid b, \text{ for some prime-}p \}$, then where does $p^t$ come from?

Comment: For any natural $t$, the number $p^t=\frac{p^t}{1}$ is an element of $R$, right? You need to show that every proper nonzero ideal contains some power of $p$.

Comment: @Mark the way $R$ is defined, according to the question, if $\frac{a}{b}\in R,$ and $p\not\mid b$ for some prime $p,$  then necessarily $p^t \not\mid b$ also,.  Is that where $p^t$ also appears?

Comment: Just noticed that the way you defined the set in the title makes no sense. Of course the denominator cannot be divisible by all primes, so this way $R$ would simply be $\mathbb{Q}$. I believe the correct definition is given in the question itself where you fix a prime $p$, and then $R$ is the subring of rational numbers where the denominator is not divisible by this specific $p$. Well, the denominator of $\frac{p^t}{1}$ is $1$, which is surely not divisible by $p$. So $p^t=\frac{p^t}{1}$ is an element of $R$.

Comment: @Mark, sorry, the way I defined $R$ in my title don't make sense?  Can you show me what the proper definition is in correct math notation.  I was trying my best translating the english into math notations.  It seems I still have ways to go before I can do it correctly most of the time.

Comment: Fix a prime $p$. Then $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}: p\nmid b\}$. Would probably be more clear if $R$ was denoted by $R_p$, to show it depends on our chosen $p$.

Comment: @Mark the way $R$ is defined, does it have to do with the $p-$adic integers or the Prufer group.  I came across both, and the definition for both seems to be very similar to how $R$ above is defined.  Also, would it be better to use the notation $R_{(p)}$ instead of $R_p$?

Comment: Being very precise, the best notation would be $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. It's a special case of a localization of a ring by a prime ideal, if you know what this is. It's not related to the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: @Mark, ah kk.  Thank you for your explanations.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: For the $N$th time, for $N\gg0$, do not use MathJax to format text. Use markdown.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought you told me MathJax is the same as LaTex.

Comment: I have never told you to use LaTeX to format text **in this forum**. In fact, I have *repeatedly* told you **not to**. I have also repeatedly explained why. And I have repeatedly told you that the text you get through MathJax can look different than regular text in other people's display (which is how I can tell at a glance that you are ***misusing*** MathJax to format text), even if you cannot see it. And I am not the only one who has told you  not to use Mathjax to format **text** in this forum. Yet you continue to do it unabated and uncaringly.

Comment: Finally, MathJax drops you into something that is *almost* (but not entirely) identical to **math mode** in LaTeX; you know, that's why you  use `$` and `$$` for it. Even if it were identical to LaTeX (which it is not), you would **not** go into math mode in LaTeX and then use `\textit` and `\textbf` *inside Math Mode* to format text. You would do it outside of math mode.