# If $I$ is an ideal of $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\not\mid b\}$, for some fixed prime $p$, show that $(p^t)\subset I.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

*Background:*

**Exercise 14:**

Let $p$ be a fixed prime integer and let $R$ be the set of all rational numbers that can be written in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ with $b$ not divisible by $p$. Prove that

*(a)* $R$ is an integral domain containing $\mathbb{Z}$.  [Note $n=\frac{n}{1}$].

*(b)*  If $\frac{a}{b}\in R$ and $p\nmid a$, then $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit in $R.$

*(c)* If $I$ is a nonzero ideal in $R$ and $I\neq R$, then $I$ contains $p^t$ for some $t>0.$.

*Questions:*

I have a question about part (c) above. I understand that I have to show if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then for some fixed prime $p,$ there exists a smallest $t>0$ such that $p^t\in I$.  First to show that $(p^t)\subset I.$ We show that $p\in I$  We have $\frac{p}{1}\in R,$ because $p\not\mid 1.$  Also, let $\frac{m}{n}\in R,$ where $p\not\mid n,$ then $p\mid m.$   Because if $p\not\mid m,$ would imply $\frac{1}{m}\in R,$ and so $m\cdot\frac{1}{m}=1\in I,$ and $I=R,$ a contradition.  Hence $p\mid m,$ and we can let the smallest integer $t>0,$ so that $p^t\mid m$ and $m=p^tw,$ where $p\not\mid w,$ then $\frac{1}{w}\in R,$ and $\frac{m}{w}=p^t\in I.$

I think I might need to do some more work to show from the conclusion that $p\mid m$, i can let the smallest integer $t>0$ so that $p^t\mid m$.  Also, the solution states to let $x=p^t\cdot \frac{a}{b},$ since $\frac{a}{b},$ is a unit by part (b) above, then $p^t=x\cdot\frac{a}{b}.$  I am not clear how the solution in the book simply could just let $x=p^t\cdot \frac{a}{b}.$

Comment: Please don't duplicate your [prior questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4866030/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I am asking a different question.  I am told if I have more than one quesiton per post, I should try to separate them.

Comment: A simpler way: using (b), you know that non-units are of the form $\dfrac{a}{b}$, where $p | a$. Then, every non-unit may be expressed as $\dfrac{p^k c}{b}$, for some $k$ and $c$ such that $p \nmid c$. Let $k_0$ be the minimum of those $k$. Try to prove that $I= (p^{k_0})
$

Comment: @JulioPuerta ,I understand that since $I\subset R,$ then $1\not\in I,$ sp every element of $I$ is a nonunit.  Can i just say that every non-unit can be expressed as $p^k\frac{a}{b}$ without showing that $p\in I$ first?

Comment: Yes, that's just the contrapositive of (b) (Also, $p$ may not be in $I$)

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in the assertion:

> "I understand that I have to show that if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then for some fixed prime $p$, there exists a smallest $t\gt 0$ such that $p^t\in I$."

First, $p$ is fixes *throughout*. It is part of the definition of $R$. Saying "for some fixed prime $p$"  after saying "If `....` then" implies that $p$ depends on the premise of the implication; here, that the choice of $p$ may depend on the choice of $I$. That is incorrect. Again, $p$ is fixed throughout the entirety of these statements.

Second, it is not true that this happens for any ideal $I$. The statement is very clear that it is restricted to **nonzero** **proper** ideals $I$.

Third, nothing in (c) talks about a "smallest" $t$; it only talks about *a* $t\gt 0$. Of course, if there are any such $t$ then there is a smallest one, *but that is immaterial and irrelevant* as far as the statement (c) is concerned.

What you need to show is *exactly* what (c) says. That if $I$ is a nonzero proper ideal of $R$, then there is a $t\gt 0$ such that $p^t\in I$. The prime $p$ is part of the definition of $R$.

To your work: showing that $p\in R$ follows simply from invoking part (b): you show in (b) that every integer is an element of $R$, so there is no reason whatsoever for proving it again.

Your argument that if $\frac{m}{n}\in I$ and $p\nmid m$ then $1\in I$ is not correct as written.  You claim that $m\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\in I$; but you do not know that $m$ is in $I$ nor that $n$ is in $I$ yet. You only know that $\frac{m}{n}\in I$. Before you assert that $m\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\in I$, you need to argue that at least one of the factors is in $I$, and you have failed to do so.

Likewise, the claim that $\frac{m}{w}\in I$ is incomplete. How do you know it lies in $I$? All you know about $I$ is that it is nonzero and it is not all of $R$. Why does it contain *that* particular element?

Note that you have failed to use that $I\neq (0)$, which suggests there are other assumptions in your argument that you are making but not explaining, rendering it at best incomplete.

The correct argument: since $I$ is nonzero, it contains a nonzero element $\frac{m}{n}$. We may assume that $\gcd(m,n)=1$. If $p\nmid m$, then $\frac{n}{m}\in R$, so $\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=1\in I$ (product of an element of $R$ by an element of $I$ lies in $I$), and therefore $I=R$. Thus, if $I\neq R$, then $p\mid m$.

Now write $m=\frac{p^tw}{n}$, with $p\nmid w$. Then $\frac{n}{w}\in R$, and therefore $\frac{n}{w}\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)\in I$ (product of an element of $R$ by an element of $I$). Thus, $\frac{n}{w}\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \frac{np^tw}{wn} = \frac{p^t}{1}\in I$, as desired.

The solution is taking $x$ to be your $\frac{m}{n}$, $b$ is your $n$, and $a$ is your $w$. So they are saying to write $x$ as $\frac{p^ta}{b}= p^t\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ with $p\nmid a$. So they are saying: since $\frac{p^ta}{b}=p^t\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\in I$, and $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit, then $p^t\in I$. It is a trivial fact that if $I$ is an ideal, and $ux\in I$ for a unit $u$, then $x\in I$.

Comment: when you say $p$ is a fixed prime throughout the entire question.  If I define $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\not\mid b, \text{ for some prime-}p \}$, won't that indicate that $p$ is a fixed prime as far as $R$ is concerned.  I mean for the purpose of the question, $p$ is assumed to be a fixed prime as long as it is related to elements of $R.$  I am not really good with points of grammar, maybe I am missisng some point of logical reasoning here.  Also I know that Bill has told me about getting better at translating english expression to math expression in my....

Comment: ..previous questions.  If I see something like $A%$ and $B$ implies $C,$ then I am usually ok.  But if i see something like $A, B$ with $D$ implies $E$, then I get stuck since I am not sure if  it is $A$ or $(B$ and $D)$ implies $E$ or ($A$ and $B$ and $E$) implies $E$.

Comment: @Seth: If you "define" $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}\mid p\nmid b\text{ for some prime }p\}$, then you are defining $R$ as $\mathbb{Q}$, because for every rational $\frac{a}{b}$ there exists a prime $p$ such that $p\nmid b$, and putting "for some prime $p$" inside the definitional clause means that $p$ depends on the choice of $\frac{a}{b}$. That is, the formula you are using to define $R$ is "there exists a $p$ such that $p\nmid b$". That is **not** the definition of $R$. The statement of the problem clearly begins by saying "Let $p$ be **a fixed prime...**"

Comment: @Seth:  Then you need to review basic logic instead of trying to do abstract algebra.

Comment: the symbolic logic course I took in philosophy, it it doesn't have a lot of prepositions or the type of sentences I see in abstract algebra.  I never have this much trouble in real or complex analysis, not even point set topology as far as these subtle lnaguage issues.

Comment: @Seth I do not think you are an impartial and sufficiently well-informed judge to determine whether or not you've had "this much trouble" in other areas. Review basic propositional calculus and mathematical, not a course taught by a philosophy department.

Comment: the math department at my university recommended us to take a course in symbolic logic., and that is all the logic we had. Unless people were going onto set theory or mathematical logic. That was it.  We did not even had one of those intro to proof courses.  They just basically expected us to read it or learn it on our own.  If nothing else, just imitate from watching our professors teaching from Spivak's big Calculus text.  There was something call intro to abstract mathematics.  But the text was Courant and Robbin's text What is Mathematics? That was it.

Comment: @Seth I do not recall asking for your story, nor is it relevant. I said you needed to review basic mathematical and propositional logic instead of trying to wade through material that you clearly find confusing.

Comment: thank you for the advice.

Comment: I relook at one of your comments and your editing of the title of my post.  You changed to "$R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\not\mid b\}$, for some fixed prime $p$."  But could I define $R$ to be $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\not\mid b \text{ for a fixed prime } p\}$?  I am not sure the difference between if i included the "for a fixed prime $p$" within the set builder notation versus outside it differ in meaning.  To me both look to me to mean the same thing.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "for some fixed $p$" is an existential statement. If you state it outside the set definition, then it's the same $p$ for all $\frac{a}{b}$: it comes *before* testing the rational. If you put it inside the set definition, then it comes *after* you take the rational. So it is the same as $\{\frac{a}{b}\mid \text{there exists some fixed prime }p\text{ such that }p\nmid b\}$. That's all of $\mathbb{Q}$, because you are allowed to pick $p$ depending on $b$.

Comment: ah kk.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: A friend explained to me what you about why $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\not\mid b \text{ for some prime }p\}$, He said it sounded ambigious because when translating to symbolic logic notation, it would be the same as: $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid \forall b\in \mathbb{Z}\exists p_0\in \mathbb{Z}, p_0\not\mid b \}$, Basically, $p_0$ depends on $b$.  What if I reverse the two quantifiers:  "$R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid \exists p_0\in \mathbb{Z}\forall b\in \mathbb{Z}, p_0 \text{ is a fixed prime, } p_0\not\mid b \}$", would it be equivalent to:...

Comment: "Let $p_0$ be a fixed prime $p$ and let $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\not\mid b\}$".  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Seth Neither of them parses, actually. Because you already have an $a$ and a $b$. Let $S$ be your set. In the second one, you are writting: $$x\in S\iff \exists a\in \mathbb{Z}, b\in\mathbb{Z}\bigl( (b\neq 0)\wedge (x=\frac{a}{b})\wedge( \exists p_0\in\mathbb{Z} \forall b\in\mathbb{Z}(p_0\text{ is a fixed prime}\wedge p_0\nmid b)\Bigr)$$ Not only is the "fixed" out of place and unintelligible, you are quantifying $b$ twice which means the second $b$ is *different* from the first. You went from writting something that made sense but was not what you wanted to something which is nonsensical.

Comment: @Seth The solution is simple and I already gave it to you. But instead you'd rather try to shoehorn what you had done and try to somehow add even more stuff to see if you can fix it. But you are only making it worse. What your friend explained is **exactly** what I had told you already.

Comment: (In addition, there is not prime $p$ such that $\forall b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $p\nmid n$, so now instead of every $b$ being possible, no prime is possible, so you went from taking all of $\mathbb{Q}$ to taking the empty set.)

Comment: @Seth: When we write $\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}\mid $`property` $\}$, if the property depends on $a$ and $b$, then we are abusing notation in a minor way to simplify the expression. We should really be writing $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ such that }x=\frac{a}{b}\text{ and }$`property` $\}$. That means that you are **already** quantifying the $b$ existentially. If a formula quantifies a variable twice, then it is equivalent to changing all occurrences within the scope of the second quantification to a new letter. (cont)

Comment: @Seth So if you write $\exists b\Bigl(\exists a(\forall b (a\nmid b))\wedge b\gt 0\Bigr)$, then that's logically equivalent to $\exists b \Bigl (\exists a (\forall c (a\nmid b))\wedge b\gt 0\Bigr)$. To avoid confusion, *we don't reuse variable names within a formula, we don't double quantify our variables*. Both your expressions double-quantify $b$, once hidden in the notation, the second time explicitly. Second, when you say $\exists p($`blah`$)$, the $p$ is **fixed** throughout `blah`. That's why putting in "fixed" inside your existential quantifier doesn't do anything but confuse. (cont)

Comment: @Seth That's why the exercise **starts** by saying "Let $p$ be a fixed prime integer." Before you define anything you are picking a $p$. It is now no longer treated as a variable, but as a **constant**. So you don't quantify it anymore, because you don't quantify constants. So you don't say "for some fixed $p$" in the middle of a set definition. That's like saying "for some fixed $3$" in the middle of the set definition.

Comment: thank you again for your detailed write up and clarification.  When I was learning symbolizing sentences with quantifiers, I often see examples with existential quantifiers for an object X with property Y be translated as something like "Let object X have property Y" or "Let X be some object having property Y", so if there is at least existence of an object X, that includes the case of the existence of a fixed object X beforehand.  Similarly, i see in the case of $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments, where it says....

Comment: ...."for any $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$.... When starting the proof, one often starts with a given $\epsilon$, then one picks a a $\delta$ depending on said $\epsilon$...  I also see examples of epsilon delta argument phrasing starting like: "For any given $\epsilon$.....  For me these little grammatical based subtle change in confusing because i am not sure if it the english reflects what the quantifiers intend to me when using them.

Comment: @Seth None of that applies to this, where the exercise begins: "Let $p$ be a fixed prime." In all those $\epsilon$-$\delta$ (hyphen, not minus sign) arguments, did any of them, after saying "Let $\epsilon\gt 0$", ever have, elsewhere within the argument, the words "for a fixed $\epsilon$"? *Anywhere?*. No.

Comment: I was trying to explain to you the cause to why I am having trouble with this simple translation exercise.  Grammatically, Let an object X be fixed, there exists some object X, let X be some/a fixed object, for any fixed object X, let object X be given, all five cases to me can be used the existential quantififer when translating into propositional calculus notation as $\exists X$.

Comment: @Seth No. They do **not** all translate as $\exists X$. For example, in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument, "let $\epsilon\gt 0$..." comes from the **universal** quantifier, not an existential one. In this exercise, if you were to translate symbolically, you would have a $p$ **universally** quantified encompassing everything, not existentially quantified. "Let $p$ be a prime" at the start $\neq$ "for some prime $p$" somewhere in the middle or at the end. I say again: You need to review **basic** mathematical logic, because you just don't know it correctly. That's why you are confused.